# Redis how to find optimal value for IOCP

Tags: multithreading, redis, timeout

Currently we are having problem using an application that makes lots of request to a Redis-instance, as the application-cache.

We received all kinds of timeouts on different operations. Like the following:

```
System.TimeoutException: Timeout performing GET MyKey, inst: 2, mgr: Inactive, 
queue: 6, qu: 0, qs: 6, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 0, ar: 0, 
IOCP: (Busy=6,Free=994,Min=4,Max=1000), 
WORKER: (Busy=3,Free=997,Min=4,Max=1000)
```

After consulting the documentation we found the following article (https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/Timeouts.md) recommending us to increase the number of WorkerThreads (default value = 4)

How can we find the optimal amount of min/max wokerthreads? Redis recommends starting with 200-300. But this seems high when we compare with the default value of 4.

What could be issues we experience when setting the number too high? Why is this default value as low as 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that when you set a value using ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(…), it doesn't mean that those many threads are spun up instantaneously or always maintained. It just means that the threadpool will provide new worker threads or I/O completion threads on demand (without any throttling) until it reaches the "Minimum" setting for each type of thread.

By default, the minimum number of threads is set to the number of processors on a system.

You do not have to set it to 200-300. You can increase it to some value (say 100) and tweak it accordingly as you need to. You will need a higher number in case of bursty loads.